# Div on top of image inside varying width div

Tags: css, responsive-design, position, media-queries, caption

I have started working with responsive design. Currently, I am having issues with putting a div with a caption over an image. Reason being is that these images have varying widths depending on screen size. These images are inside of divs of varying width depending on the screen size as well.

Is there a way to have a consistent width caption div over the image without writing CSS for each media query? Thanks for any help.

HTML Markup:

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3 buffer portfolio logo thumbnail-tall">
        <img class="img-responsive img-center" src="http://placekitten.com/260/430" alt="" />
        <div class="image-hover">
            <h3>Test Title</h3>
            <p>This is some descriptive text.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS (Sass):

```
div.portfolio{
    position: relative;
    div.image-hover{
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        width: 90%; //This does not stay consistent for each media query and varying image widths
        height: 100%;
        background: rgb(0,0,0); // backwards compatibility for older browsers
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        display: none;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        h3{ color: #fff; }
    }
}

div.portfolio:hover{
    div.image-hover{ 
        display: block;
        z-index: 100;
    }
}
```

Live Test Site page: http://dai2.designangler.com/work

Comment: If I understand your question right, the problem is that the caption overlay (the black transparent one) doesn't always cover your pictures?

Comment: @RomainBraun It is an issue of varying widths. The width varies on the images themselves, the container they are in, and depending on the screen size, also based on the media query. I am trying to see if there is a solution that would not require me to write code for each targeted media query as the column widths(div containing the image and caption) change at each targeted media query.

Comment: @RomainBraun Also, I am using the Twitter Bootstrap framework if that helps you understand the issue.

Comment: Could you just simply answer yes or no? Your explanation really doesn't help me understand the problem.

Comment: @RomainBraun Yes, that is the basic issue.

Comment: Mmmh I'd recommend adding your image-hover div with a css pseudo-element, like img:after. This way it will get your image dimensions. Do you think you see how to do so?

Comment: @RomainBraun I have not worked with the :before and :after pseudo elements much. I am not entirely sure how I would implement this.